# Django app runs via runserver but errors via mod_wsgi (NoReverseMatch error)

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have an interesting situation:

I have a django app as follows:

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 4 Tintin Tintin 4096 Jul 31 18:50 app_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  335 Aug  1 12:55 django.wsgi
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  252 Jul 31 18:48 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 Tintin Tintin 4096 Jul 31 18:50 Main_app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  272 Aug  1 10:42 uwsgi.ini
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$
```

---

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin    0 Jul 31 18:48 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  149 Jul 31 18:49 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 6178 Aug  1 11:45 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 3428 Jul 31 18:49 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  985 Aug  1 12:49 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  408 Jul 31 18:48 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 1428 Jul 31 18:48 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 1049 Jul 31 18:50 wsgi.pyc
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$
```

---

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$ cat urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                  # URL to app_1/
                  url(r'^app_1/', include('app_1.urls', namespace='app_1_namespace'))
)
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles DjangoProj]$
```

---

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles app-1]$ ls -l
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin    0 Jul 31 18:48 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  156 Jul 31 18:50 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin   57 Jul 31 18:48 models.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  210 Jul 31 18:50 models.pyc
drwxrwxr-x 3 Tintin Tintin 4096 Jul 31 18:48 static
drwxrwxr-x 3 Tintin Tintin 4096 Jul 31 18:48 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  383 Jul 31 18:48 tests.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  775 Jul 31 18:48 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin  717 Jul 31 18:48 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 2961 Jul 31 18:48 views.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tintin Tintin 3150 Jul 31 18:48 views.pyc
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles app-1]$
```

---

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # Match the index.html page.
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='home_page'),
                       # Show the appropriate environment.
                       url(r'^show_environment/(?P<environment_name>\w+)/$',
                           views.show_environment,
                        name="show_environment_name"),
                       # About page.
                       url(r'^show_about/$', views.show_about, name='show_about'),
                       # Show archive data.
                       url (r'^request_archive_data/$', views.show_request_archive_page, name='request_archive_data')
                       )
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles app-1]$
```

So here is the fun part... the app work's great when I run it via runserver. But when I run it deployed behind Apache, I see the following in **django_logs.log**

```
ERROR 2013-08-01 08:55:30,066 base 18235 140176797026304 Line# 215: Internal Server Error: /app_1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/Tintin/Programs/Django/Main_app/app_1/views.py", line 17, in index
    return HttpResponse(template.render (context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 424, in render
    raise e
NoReverseMatch: u"'app_1_namespace" is not a registered namespace
```

I then modified my Project to not use namespaces and modified the templates as such. I now observe that I get the same error when the render function tries to do a reverse URL lookup on the first url of home_page.

Here is the template at which I get the error:

```
<a class="brand" href="{% url 'app_1_namespace:home_page' %}">Home</a>
```

I am using django 1.4

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles Main_app]$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 23 2013, 07:53:20)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 3, 'final', 0)
>>> exit()
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles Main_app]$
```

---

```
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles Main_app]$ cat django.wsgi
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Main_app.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/Tintin/.python-eggs'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

path = '/home/Tintin/Programs/Django/Main_app'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
[Tintin@BlisteringBarnacles Main_app]$
```

I read through the Django apps and scouring the web did not yield many results. Maybe I am missing something really simple. I would appreciate an input on this one.

Regards...

Comment: Can you show content of wsgi file?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have updated the post with the contents of the wsgi file.

Comment: Is it working when you get rid of namespace in urls.py in Main_app?

Comment: Nope. As mentioned, it then error's at the first href it finds in the template. It seems like it is not even loading the app_1's url's.

Comment: Ok, reason of error is in template, try to put '{% load url from future %}' in your template that you are rendering, and {% load app_1_namespace %}

Comment: Hi Adam, I was going to put in the load url from future but I backed off ... not sure why. And again not sure why it works via the dev server. But let me try what you suggested.

Comment: No luck with that either... I tried the load url from future but and loading of tag fails. And besides, that's used for custom tags. I don't have any custom tags... just using namespaces.

Comment: Adam - I finally got it to work by saying load url from future. Initially I kept getting error's despite touching django.wsgi. But a stop and start of apache httpd seems to have fixed it. Tested it from different machines. Many Thanks Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Adam - I finally got it to work by saying load url from future. Initially I kept getting error's despite touching django.wsgi. But a stop and start of apache httpd seems to have fixed it. Tested it from different machines. Many Thanks Sir!!